# How do we call this type of Bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How do we call this type of Bar, which could be modified with the mouse not like in the case of Progressive Bars?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a [range](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php)?

Comment: I think so ! Thank you very much

Comment: I would call it a slider, range would have two "dots" IMHO

Comment: @JonSG in HTML, it's a range

Comment: I understand that, but in the same way as one might talk about a gui element being "dropdown" rather than a "select",  I think when describing such a gui element as this I would use the term "slider" rather than a specific input tag type identifier.  In fact, your link makes liberal use of the term slider to describe this type of control.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for the Help :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of component is called `range` in the context of a HTML form.

There is a [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_range) available at [W3schools' HTML Input Types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) page.

It can also be referred to as a `slider` in case of [JQuery ui slider component](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) for example.

In any case, both slider or range are quite self-explainatory terms that can be used to describe this kind of component.